# No warning in first posts review queue when trying to edit question with not approved edits

Tags: bug, first-post-review

See https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22230885 (review regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735213/how-can-i-display-or-declare-table-name-after-writing-dml-trigger-i-can-declare)) for some example of a post in the review queue which has some not approved edits.

Therefore if I try to edit the question directly, it states

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot
>   be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

But in the review queue itself, when trying to edit the question it simply doesn't do anything and no warning is raised - therefore one is not aware of why he/she is not able to edit it.

Do other users also face this problem or it is somehow reproducible?

Comment: Confirmed, this is a bug, and it has been reported many times. I haven't seen any progress on a fix, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh Sorry, didn't found that. Thanks for clarifying!